# ColdFusion 9 server not restaring - “Permission denied” errors

Tags: java, coldfusion

I had to restart my ColdFusion 9 server on CentOS because of a memory performance issue, but now the server won't restart again. When looking at `cfserver.log` I can see how there's "Permission denied" errors all along.

The ColdFusion application folder (`/opt/coldfusion9/`) is owned by `nobody:root`, as that fixed a similar problem that we had a few weeks ago. Also, the last time this CF server was running correctly, the JRE user that was being used was `nobody`.

Maybe CF is trying to restart using another user (presumably `apache`) and that creates permission issues? However, I'm not sure how to check this hypothesis.

Where's the config file that tells CF what JRE user to utilize? If I can change that, I could try to specify `nobody` there.

Any other ideas also welcome.

**UPDATE:**

The runtime user that Coldfusion will utilise is defined in `/etc/init.d/coldfusion_9`. I fixed the problem by being consistent with the users: I needed to revert the ownership of the folder `/opt/coldfusion9/` back to `apache:root`, which matches the init file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the runtime user that Coldfusion is starting at by looking in the start up script:

/etc/init.d/coldfusion_9

The look for the for the following line:

RUNTIME_USER=""[user_will_be_here]""

Comment: That's useful, I've just checked that I have "nobody" as the RUNTIME_USER. However, after the last successful restart, CF's runtime user is set to "apache", contradicting what's in the init file. Is this setting being overwritten by something else?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. How did you restart CF? using /etc/init.d/coldfusion_9 restart

Comment: No, using /opt/coldfusion9/bin/coldfusion restart

Comment: That probably makes sense then. Check the "runtime_user" setting in that file. I would assume it is set differently to the one in the /etc/init.d/coldfusion_9 file, hence it starting with different users. When the system starts it will use the file in /etc/init.d/ however when you did it manually you used the file in the CF directory and if they are different then that is going to happen.

Comment: The init file in /opt/coldfusion9/bin/ actually works off the main init file /etc/init.d/coldfusion_9. I just fixed the problem by being consistent with the user defined in the init and the user that owns the CF folder (as reflected in the question update)